# Storing implemented classes with static methods in a dictionary: Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, static

I have an abstract class that has child classes inheriting it. It also have a static function that contains some hard-coded data per class.

I also have a class map that ties strings to the classes B and C. When I try to specify the type def for that map I get type Errors.

If I use `new () => A` I can't use the static methods.

If I use `typeof A` I can't create a new class instance with it.

```
abstact class A {
  static getSomeData(): string { return ''; }
  abstract doSomething(): void { }
}

class B extends A {
  getSomeData(): string { return 'hello' }
  doSomething(): {}
}

class C extends A {
  getSomeData(): string { return 'bye' }
  doSomething(): {}
}

const classMap: { [id: string]: SOMETHING_HERE } = {
  first: B,
  second: C
}

///////
// Later
// I want to be able to both of these without TS complaining about types

classMap['first'].getSomeData();
new classMap['first']()
```

What do I need to do to specify the type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is `typeof A & (new () => A)` will do.

However I suggest to reconsider the pattern you are using:

- constructors aren't designed to be used with polymorphism since they are not instance methods, they are more likely a special static method. For example when a base class defines a public method, all its descendants must expose that method too. This does not apply to a constructor - a descendant doesn't have to expose public constructor at all.
- static methods aren't supposed to be used with polymorphism for the same reason.

Although you can do both in ES6/Typescript, I wouldn't advise to do it since such exotic combination of structural typing with class polymorphism will be difficult to understand by anyone who reads the code. This is also why typing such thing is so tricky (although still possible).

Why don't you just use simple objects with even simpler types like this?

```
interface A {
  getSomeData(): string;
  createInstance(): {
    doSomething(): void;
  };
}
const B: A = {
  getSomeData() {
    return 'hello';
  }
  createInstance() {
    return {
      doSomething() {}
    };
  }
}
const C: A = {
  getSomeData() {
    return 'bye';
  }
  createInstance() {
    return {
      doSomething() {}
    };
  }
}

const classMap: { [id: string]: A } = {
  first: B,
  second: C
};

classMap['first'].getSomeData();
classMap['first'].createInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks. The reason I used inheritance instead of interfaces is that B and C share a fair number of methods in my actual code that I just didn't include for simplicity.

Comment: Depends on how your actual code looks like, but you can extend interfaces too, then instantiate objects conforming to them like `const B = {...methodsForA, definitionsSpecificToB}`.